# Uncaught TypeError: extract(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, themes

My WordPress site is using a custom theme written by a third-party. I am getting the white screen error on my pages saying `There has been a critical error on this website.`

In attempt to diagnose the error I turned on debugging in the `wp-config.php` file with the following:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

I then checked the `wp-content/debug.log` and found the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: extract(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in /home/.../public_html/.../wp-content/themes/.../includes/shortcodes/shortcode.tabs/_shortcode.advanced.tabs.php:301`

The `_shortcode.advanced.tabs.php` section of code with the error is below. Line 301 with the error is near the beginning:

`extract($this->atts[ $this->id ]);`

```php
function register_tab_item($atts, $tab_content =  NULL){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'title'             => '',
        'icon'              => '',
        'hash'              => '',
    ), $atts));

    if ( !isset($this->child[ $this->id ]) )
        $this->child[ $this->id ] = 0;

    $this->child[ $this->id ]++;

    extract($this->atts[ $this->id ]);

    $i = $this->child[ $this->id ]; 
    $tabs_count = $this->total[ $this->id ]; 

    $icon = cloudfw_make_icon($icon, 'ui--icon');

    $hash = sanitize_html_class( $hash, "tab-". $this->id ."-{$i}" );
    if ( !empty($hash) && ($hash[strlen($hash)-1] == '/') )
            $hash .= '/';

    if ( empty($title) && empty($icon) )
        $title = "Tab {$i}";


    $title = html_entity_decode(stripcslashes($title)); 

    $this->titles[ $this->id ] .= "<li class=\"";
    if ( empty($title) ) {
        $this->titles[ $this->id ] .= ' empty-title';
    }

    $this->titles[ $this->id ] .= "\">";
    if ( $title_element ) {
        $this->titles[ $this->id ] .= "<$title_element>";
    }

        $this->titles[ $this->id ] .= "<a href=\"#{$hash}\">{$icon}{$title}</a>";

    if ( $title_element ) {
        $this->titles[ $this->id ] .= "</$title_element>";
    }
    $this->titles[ $this->id ] .= "</li>";


    $tab_content = do_shortcode($tab_content);
    $this->contents[ $this->id ] .= "<li class=\"hidden\">";
    $this->contents[ $this->id ] .= "{$tab_content}</li>";

}
```

**EDIT**

I attempted to log more of the variables to help diagnose the error.

The variable logging is as follows:

```php
$this->atts = $atts;
var_dump($this->id);
var_dump($this->atts);
var_dump($this->atts[ $this->id ]);
```

I am setting `$this->atts = $atts;` because `$this->atts` was empty before.

`$this->id` is set to `int(0)`.
`$this->atts` is set to `array(1) { ["title"]=> string(8) "Overview" }`.

`$this->atts[ $this->id ]` is returning `NULL` though. I'm not sure why this is though as I assume you can do index selection with an array in `php`.

Comment: `extract($this->atts[ $this->id ]);` doesn't make sense, `extract` expects an array, but also `extract` is a well known antipattern with security consequences. In my opinion that line can just be deleted and serves no useful purpose.